# Sortable js not working in mobile browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Below is the sortable jquery code and it's working fine in dasktop but in mobile browser not working so please suggest how to resolved... ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#post_list").sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        handle: ".socialmediaspacing",
        delayOnTouchOnly: true,
        update: function(event, ui) {
          var post_order_ids = new Array();
          $('#post_list div.listitems').each(function() {
            post_order_ids.push($(this).data("post-id"));
          });
          $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
              post_order_ids: post_order_ids,
              "_token": "{{csrf_token()}}"
            },
            success: function(data) {
              $('#socail-profile-mobileview').html(data);
              Snackbar.show({
                  pos: 'bottom-right',
                  text: "Ordering changed successfully.",
                  actionText: 'Okay'
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
      $( "#post_list" ).disableSelection();
    });
```

Comment: Please remove `php` and `mysql` tags as they are not relevant

Answer (score 7):

This is due to touch events not being correctly identified.

You can either write your own events, or use a library to do so. For a similar purpose, I am using [jQuery UI Touch Punch](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch) and it works great.

You just need to include the `.js` file **after** the `jquery-ui.js`

```
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

Nothing else is required and all the standard jquery-ui functions should now work on touch devices to: `sortable`, `draggable` etc..

Comment: Best and most simple solution to fix mobile issues with sorting items on mobile devices +1